# HINT: Prove there does not exist a rational number that satisfies $x^3=p/q$

Tags: rational-numbers

I would like to request a hint for a problem I am working on form Hardy's a Course of Pure Mathematics.

**Question** 
Prove generally that a rational fraction $p/q$ in its lowest terms cannot be the cube of a rational function unless $p$ and $q$ are perfect cubes.

**My Work**

Claim: $\nexists x\in \mathbb Q$ such that $x^3=\dfrac{p}{q}$ unless $\sqrt[3]{p} , \sqrt[3]{q} \in \mathbb Z$

Attempt: Since $x$ is a rational number, it can be written as the ratio of two integers, $w$ and $v$. $x=w/v$ Therefore, we have:

$\dfrac{w^3}{v^3}=\dfrac{p}{q}$

Since $p$ and $q$ are in lowest possible terms, we can infer that both cannot be even.

Rearranging the above, we get:

$w^3 \times q=v^3 \times p$

Based on this, we can identify two possible cases:

1) $w^3$ and $p$ are even and $v^3$ and $q$ are odd.

2) Vice-verse

---

My problem is that I cannot seem to carry the proof from here.

Another potential root I was thinking of going was basing a proof on the fact that $p$ and $q$ are integers and then seeing if I can find a contradiction, but I am at a loss on how to begin it this way.

Comment: So you can again assume $gcd(v,w)=1$. Notice that since $gcd(p,q)=1$, then in the equation $w^3q=v^3p$, you MUST have $q|v$ by the fundamental theorem of algebra. So $v=xq$ for some $x$. What can you now say about $w$?

Comment: It is not clear what th problem is. It reads "rational function." Rational function with coefficients in what? The beginning of your solution seems to be dealing with rational *numbers* $p/q$. so which is it, rational functions over some field, or rational numbers?

Comment: @Alex Please excuse my mathematical ignorance, but what does $q|v$ stand for?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you for pointing out that error, I meant to write rational number.

Comment: $q|v$ means that $q$ divides into $v$ with no remainder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may assume that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime. Suppose there are relatively prime integers $a$ and $b$ such that $\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^3=\dfrac{p}{q}$. 
Then 
$$a^3q=b^3p.\tag{$1$}$$

It is easy to see that $a^3$ and $b^3$ are relatively prime. For if they are not, then there is a prime $r$ that divides both. But then $r$ divides $a$ and $b$.

Now argue that  $a^3$ divides $p$ and $p$ divides $a^3$. Since you asked for a hint, we leave this part out.

Conclude from the above result that $p=\pm a^3$.

A similar argument shows that $q$ is the cube of an ineger.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ By the Rational Root Test, $\rm\:(a,b)=1,\  \left(\dfrac{a}b\right)^3\! =\dfrac{p}q\:\Rightarrow\:\begin{eqnarray}\rm a\mid p\\ \rm b\mid q\end{eqnarray}\:\Rightarrow\: \left(\dfrac{a}b\right)^2\! =\dfrac{p/a}{q/b}.\:$ Iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Problem : Prove generally that a rational fraction in its lowest terms cannot be the cube of a rational number unless p  and q are both perfect cubes.

proof:
We have, 
p/q = k^3
let us suppose that x and y are the cube roots of p and q respectively then,

```
  x^3 = p
  y^3 = q
```

Now,
   p/q = k^3
or, p  = k^3 . q
or, x^3= k^3 . y^3 
Hence,
     x = k.y
or,x/y = k

Therefore, this only comes true when x and y are the cube roots of p and q respectively.

Answer (score -1):

What about $x=1, p=1$, and $q=1$? I'm pretty sure $1$ is a rational number, and $1/1$ is in its lowest terms.

Comment: 1 is a perfect cube